# How to make image left and span right on <center>?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make an image left and a `<span class="badge badge-primary">v 2.1</span>` on right,all these items are on `<center>`.

code:

```
<center><div class="card" style="margin-top: 5px; border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-radius: 4px; border-width: 4px;">
  <img src="../install/images/brand/logo_wide.webp" alt="Thos Host Billing Software"><span class="badge badge-primary">v 2.1</span>
  <div class="container">
    // something    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'center' is an obsolete element and should not longer be used

Comment: Thanks for advice, but, what do you suggest to use instead of <center>?

Comment: There are many methods of centering. I suggest you search for those

Comment: okay, i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<center>` tag is obsolete and shouldn't be used. Use flexbox instead because it's much easier.

Flexbox documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Check out my demo. If you don't use `align-items-*` class you need to wrap both `<img>` and `<span>` in `<div>` because otherwise it will be stretched vertically.

```css
img{height:100px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/camera.png" alt="">
    <span class="badge badge-primary">v 2.1</span>
</div>
```